# Having a variable typed class member depending on type of template C++

Tags: c++, templates, cuda

I'm trying to write a template class for managing pointers on Host and Nvidia GPU, similar to `boost::shared_ptr`. For doing this, I need to define 2 pointers, one for Host and one for GPU in the class.

```
template<typename T>
class GPUSharedPtr
{
  protected:

  T *cpu_pointer;
  T *gpu_pointer;
}
```

The problem with CUDA is that it defines it's own types for `std::complex<double>` and `std::complex<float>`, which are `cuDoubleComplex` and `cuComplex` respectively.

```
template<typename std::complex<double> >
class GPUSharedPtr
{
  protected:

  std::complex<double> *cpu_pointer;
  cuDoubleComplex *gpu_pointer;
}


template<typename std::complex<float> >
class GPUSharedPtr
{
  protected:

  std::complex<float> *cpu_pointer;
  cuComplex *gpu_pointer;
}
```

How can I have different typed pointers for GPU in these two cases?

Thanks!

Comment: Two important questions: are you using C++11 and do you have other functions that already link these two types together (specifically something that takes a CPU type and returns the GPU type equivalent).  If yes to both you can use typeof and type inference to get what you want.

Comment: Why do you need two raw pointers per smart pointer?

Comment: @Speed8ump: Yes, I'm using C++11. I don't know if there are functions that return the equivalent GPU type. There are only 2 types defined differently in CUDA, so I can define such functions.

Comment: @JaredHoberock: I need to manage the same data on both GPU and CPU and avoid transfers when the data is already present on the GPU. I also need the pass the pointers around a lot, this is a good way to ensure that there are no memory leaks or undefined references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not adding both as template parameters :

```
template<typename CPU_T, typename GPU_T>
class GPUSharedPtr
{
  protected:
      CPU_T *cpu_pointer;
      GPU_T *gpu_pointer;
};

int main()
{
    GPUSharedPtr<std::complex<double> , cuDoubleComplex> g1;
    GPUSharedPtr<std::complex<float> , cuComplex> g2;
    return 0;
}
```

Or (if it makes more sense in you case), you can use tag dispatching as suggested by MooingDuck to properly default the value of the GPU pointer type :

```
template<class CPU_T> struct DefaultGPU_T { typedef CPU_T type;};
template<> struct DefaultGPU_T<std::complex<double>> { typedef cuDoubleComplex type;};
template<> struct DefaultGPU_T<std::complex<float>> { typedef cuComplex type;};

template<typename CPU_T, typename GPU_T=typename DefaultGPU_T<CPU_T>::type>

class GPUSharedPtr
{
protected:
    CPU_T *cpu_pointer;
    GPU_T *gpu_pointer;
};

int main()
{
    GPUSharedPtr<int> g0;
    GPUSharedPtr<std::complex<double>> g1;
    GPUSharedPtr<std::complex<float>> g2;
    return 0;
}
```

---

[**Live demo.**](http://ideone.com/DcNL5p)

Comment: And maybe use `CPU_T` as default for `GPU_T` for cases when both are the same?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : Yes maybe, but from the OP description of the CUDA ptr, it looks like it should not be the case (ie they will always differ), so maybe defaulting it wont help ?

Comment: I didn't come up with the answer, I merely expanded it.  Feel free to edit it in if you want.

Comment: Thanks! Having the GPU_T = CPU_T by default would be cleaner. We can also have a check in the constructor if the two types are interchangeable:

Comment: Added the tag dispatching example, no p.

Comment: Awesome! Didn't know C++ templates can be this powerful. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, most reasonable solution is probably to take two template arguments, with the second being assigned the first parameter as default:

```
template<typename T, typename GPUType = T>
class GPUSharedPtr
{
  protected:

  T *cpu_pointer;
  GPUType *gpu_pointer;
};
```

Then you can typedef e.g.

```
typedef GPUSharedPtr<std:.complex<float>, cuComplex> ComplexPtr;
```

Comment: Better yet, use tag dispatching: ideone.com/DcNL5p